Using Angular router outlet in overlay
I want to use router outlet in dynamically added overlay element. I have route which is opening overlay on init and component rendered on overlay has his own router outlet. I also use ViewContainerRef of AccountComponent and add custom container so overlay markup is placed inside Angular DOM.
constructor(
    private overlay: DynamicOverlay,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private router: Router
  ) { 

openModal() {
    let config = new OverlayConfig();

      config.width = "90vw";
      config.height = "90vh";
      config.hasBackdrop = true;
      config.backdropClass = ['cdk-overlay-backdrop--light'];

      this.overlay.setContainerElement(this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement);

      const overlayRef = this.overlay.create(config);

      const portalInjector = Injector.create({
        providers: []
      });
      
      const newPortal = new ComponentPortal(
        AccountPageComponent,
        this.viewContainerRef,
        portalInjector
      )
      const ref = overlayRef.attach(newPortal);

  } 

Overlay is created right after  tag. Routes looks like this:
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
        {
          path: 'account',
          component: AccountComponent,
          children: [
            {
              path: 'pets',
              component: PetComponent,
            }
          ]
        },
...
]

As you can see when navigating to /account using primary outlet I want to open overlay and it works. Then on navigating to /account/pets I want to use outlet created in overlay. Unfortuantely in this router the account page is rendered again so it creates infinite loop of opening overlays.
I was hoping that when I create overlay in AccountComponent his <router-outlet> will act as regular child outlet but it looks that is not so simple. Does anyone knows way to fix it?
